# EigenValue and EigenVector Java Implementation

Tags: eigenvector, eigenvalue, jama

I'm implementing metric learning algorithm, I want to reduce the dimension of the data. I am using Java and libraries (Jama) to implement, and PCA to reduce the dimension. 
When I used the eig from Jama library to get eigenvalues, it takes a lots of time even for a matrix of size 300 by 20. I need to get get java implementation of Eigenvalue and eigenvector. For your information, i tried also other libraries like Jblas which has PCA, but the performance is really poor in eigenvalue and eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Apache math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) library. Search for the class [EigenDecomposition](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/index.html) in package org.apache.commons.math3.linear. By the way I think you can only find eigenvalues and eigenvectors of square matrices.

Comment: Sure it has to be square matrix,